# Is there any way to select specific tree roots with their descendants?

Tags: typeorm

**Problem** (Hypothetical scenario)
I have two entities: `House` and `Person`. Each `House` has an array of people that lives in there, and each `Person` can have children (as an array of `Person`), a parent (a `Person` too, naturally) and a `House`.

`Person` is a Tree Entity. How can I select a house with the people in a **tree structure**?

**What I've tried**

- `houseRepo.find({ relations: ['people'] })`
  This gives me an array of `House`, each having an flat array of the people that lives in the house.
  *(If there is no other way, I will use this approach and change the array into a tree structure array manually.)*
- I've tried to use the function that typeorm uses to set the relations between the objects, but unfortunately I can't just import/require it.
- (That's it for now)

**Code**
House Entity:

```js
@Entity()
export class House {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(type => Person, p => p.house)
    people: Person[];
}
```

Person Entity:

```js
@Entity()
@Tree('closure-table')
export class Person {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @TreeParent()
    parent: Person;

    @TreeChildren()
    children: Person[];

    @ManyToOne(type => House, h => h.people)
    house: House;
}
```

**What I expect**

```
// House object
{
    "id": 1,

    // People living in the house, in a tree structure
    "people": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Parent 1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Child 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Child 2"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Parent 2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Child 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Child 2"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find out how?

Comment: @Nishant, not that I remember. Sorry :T

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the tree decorators, note down that you need to use "tree repositories" [as explained in the docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/tree-entities.md#working-with-tree-entities), because right now you are using a usual repository.

So, mostly what you want is:

```js
const manager = getManager();
const trees = await manager.getTreeRepository(House).findTrees();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. The `House` entity is not a Tree (it does not have a `House` parent), [so I can't decorate the class with @Tree() and cannot use getTreeRepository(House)](https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-repository). My problem is that I want to select one specific `House`, joining all the people who lives in there, but the people has to be in a tree structure.

Comment: How do i add where clause in findDescendantsTree, it takes only relations and depth option, i also want to add custom fields query in that